# Browser for CSS shaders?

Tags: css, browser, graphics, new-operator, shader

Is there a browser which supports [CSS shaders](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/custom/index.html)?

Answer (score 7):

At the time of this writing, CSS Custom Filters, formerly known as CSS Shaders, are not available in any browser. They were an experimental feature available in WebKit Nightly and Chrome (under a flag) for a while, but have since been removed.

Comment: As of 6/16/2014, it appears that Chrome v35 does not have this flag anymore. Is this intended?

Comment: @DiodeDan Yes, that's correct. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4):

No modern browser supports CSS Shaders or its later name, CSS Custom Filters.

**Where to search for which browsers support various features:**

[Searching caniuse.com for CSS Custom Filters](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20custom%20filters) should provide an up-to-date answer to this question.

Can I Use is a great tool that provides compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more in desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: Edited to heed advice from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216568/should-an-explicit-answer-be-given-to-a-time-sensitive-question-or-is-linking-to/

Comment: This question is about shaders, ie. custom filters. It appears that no browser supports this.

Comment: Thanks, John. Not sure how I missed that until now. I made a quick update to not continue pushing bad info. I think I can improve this more but this makes it less wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Support for CSS Shaders was discontinued in Webkit in January 2014.

https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2014-January/026098.html

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some support for it and, I think, FF might have some now. I don't have my link for articles in Chrome handy but it's all very new.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser supports every feature of HTML5 and CSS3. The only one that supports it by now is Chrome I guess.

Comment: note that not all browsers that support HTML5 and CSS3 support *every* feature of those two technologies.  Take IE9 for example.  It claims CSS3 support but [lacks many of it's cool features](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-support-ie9/)

Answer (score 0):

Webkit appears to start having them: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/103170

Answer (score 0):

this link is supported for you to know the css supported browser.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/custom/index.html

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73317

chrome and safari are supported for CSS shaders